# Insert Into access aspx.vb

Tags: vb.net

I reviewed all topics and I can't find an answer to this problem I have.
 When the webpage is trying to make the Insert I received an error on

Line 30:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

My code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlString, FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, Days As String

    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('¡Gracias por participar! Tu información ha sido ingresada correctamente, posteriormente estarás recibiendo un correo indicándote los resultados de la selección.¡Suerte!!');</script>")

    FName = Name.Text
    LName = Last.Text
    Account = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Supervisor = Sup.Text
    Type = Typ.Text
    Justification = Jus.Text
    Days = Dayi.Text

    myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\Users\fernmarc\Documents\WebSite3\WebSite7\Database4.accdb")

    myConn.Open()
    sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (First, Last, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, When) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @Account, @Supervisor, @Type, @Justification, @Days) "
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, myConn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConn.Close()



End Sub
```

What I'm Missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the error details

Comment: Sure, the error appears like this:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

you insert query should be like this

```
 sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (First, Last, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, When) VALUES ( " + FName + "," + LName + "," + Account + "," + Supervisor + "," + Type  "," + Justification + "," +  Days + ")"
```

Comment: Same error. In the Line 30,   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
I added a "+" a the end of type, I also tried this:
sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (First, Last, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, Day) VALUES ('" + FName + "', '" + LName + "', '" + Account + "', '" + Supervisor + "', '" + Type + "', '" + Justification + "', '" + Days + "' ) "

Whit the same results.

Comment: Just share your updated code, let me see what exactly you are doing

Comment: just copy paste above

Comment: I Already made this, I was showing other option that I tryed. The code is the same as above (The one of my question) I only changed this part as your requested:

sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (First, Last, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, When) VALUES ( " + FName + "," + LName + "," + Account + "," + Supervisor + "," + Type + "," + Justification + "," + Days + ")"

Maybe the problem is in here:

myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\Users\fernmarc\Documents\WebSite3\WebSite7\Database4.accdb")

I'm Using Access 2013 and Visual Studio Ult 2013

Comment: You better come in chat

Comment: I cannot write in chat, because I'm a new user.

Comment: is it showing syntax error, if so problem lies in your sql string only

Comment: I found that First, Last and Type are reserverd words for Access. I modified that in Access and the code, and I have other error:

No value given for one or more required parameters.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.